# Textbox not getting focused on mouse click

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a group of Input controls with type="text in a kendo popup window (I'm using Jquery and knockout js in my page), when I move from one textbox to another by using mouse click then that textbox is not getting focused.

The focus appears when I double click on the textbox.

- This works fine in chrome, the problem is there with IE.

Can anyone please advice me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post your (relevant and [short, self-contained correct/compilable example](http://sscce.org/)) HTML, and any JavaScript that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have much information regarding the issue. However I think you're asking the same question I was trying to solve. If so, I posted the question on Telerik's support site and just received a response.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/textbox-in-popup-doesn-t-get-focus-when-mouse-clicked-in-ie.aspx

and Telerik's response:

> Indeed, there were some focus-related issues in the Kendo UI Window in our latest official release, which are now fixed. I followed the outlined steps with the current Kendo UI source code and the problem was not exhibited, so I can suggest you to try using the latest internal build. Sorry about the inconvenience caused.